# C++ parent method access to child pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, parent-child, code-organization

I'm pretty new to C++ and I am working in a little roguelike game. I have a generic class named `Actor`, which has 2 child classes, `NPC` and `Player`. The idea is for each child to contain specific data, such as experience provided by killing an NPC or the Player's stats, and special methods. On the other hand, `Actor` contains general methods such as move, because both player and NPC should move.

Now I have a `vector of NPC pointers`, and my move method should check if the target tile is occupied by an NPC (and some other NPC info), but I don't have access to that class from `Actor`. I added a forward declaration to `NPC` inside of `Actor`, but then I get this error:

> pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed

because forward declaration is not enough to access `NPC` methods.

**Actor.h:**

```
class NPC; // Forward declaration.

class Actor
{
    public:
    void move(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<NPC>> & NPCs);
}
```

**Actor.cpp:**

```
void Actor::move(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<NPC>> & NPCs)
{
    // Go through the NPCs.
    for (const auto &NPC : NPCs)
    {
        if (NPC->getOutlook() > 0) ... // Error.
    }
}
```

I could put the move method inside both `NPC` and `Player`, but I would be duplicating code, and that's a pretty bad idea.

What would be the best solution here? I guess there is a better way to organize this, but it seems pretty logical as it is. Maybe some kind of inheritance or virtual functions magic?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Have you included the header file where the `NPC` class is defined into your `Actor.cpp` source file? If you want to use members of a class, you need the class definition.

Comment: You probably want to `#include "NPC.h"` at the top of Actor.cpp.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause circular includes?

Comment: No, the trick is to only have `Actor.cpp` include `NPC.h`, and `NPC.cpp` can also include `Actor.h`. The header files must not include each other. There are some caveats with this, like your interfaces cannot take `NPC` by value. But I think if you do that, and forward declare `NPC` at the top of your `Actor.h` file, that should be enough.

Comment: I see, in the .cpp doesn't cause trouble. I feel so dumb xD. Thanks!

Comment: @JoePerkins np!

Comment: On a sidenote, shouldn't `if (NPC->getOutlook() > 0) ... // Error.` rather be `if (NPC.getOutlook() > 0) ... // Error.` since `NPC` is a reference and not a pointer?

Comment: Nope, it works, I guess because it's a reference to a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to include the header where NPC is defined in Actor.cpp, otherwise the definition of NPC will be missing.

```
// Actor.cpp
#include "NPC.h"

void Actor::move(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<NPC>> & NPCs)
{
    // Go through the NPCs.
    for (const auto &NPC : NPCs)
    {
        if (NPC->getOutlook() > 0) ... // Now you'll be able to access this.
    }
}
```